# Scalatest / Sbt / Akka-TestKit Issue in Testing Persistent Actor

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt, akka, scalatest, akka-testkit

I'm running test with Akka TestKit on a Persistent Actor.

An odd problem that i am facing is that, despite me, cleaning the persistent folders before or after each test, when i run my full test suite with sbt, The persistent folders seems not to be removed. This is a problem, because from one test scenario to the next, data persisted are carried. When the next scenario start, the actor recover data from the previous scenario, which falsify its test.

This happens only when i run with sbt. If I run it with Intellij, i do not have the problem, all my test scenario is ran perfectly

Please see below my PersistenceSpec that I mixin on my Test.

```
abstract class PersistenceSpec(system: ActorSystem) extends TestKit(system)
  with ImplicitSender
  with FeatureSpecLike
  with Matchers
  with GivenWhenThen
  with BeforeAndAfterAll
  with BeforeAndAfterEach
  with PersistenceCleanup {

  def this(name: String, config: Config) = this(ActorSystem(name, config))

  override protected def beforeAll()     = deleteStorageLocations()

  override protected def afterAll() = {
    deleteStorageLocations()
    TestKit.shutdownActorSystem(system)
  }


  override protected def beforeEach() : Unit = {
    deleteStorageLocations()
    super.beforeEach()
  }

  override protected def afterEach(): Unit = {
    super.afterEach()
    deleteStorageLocations()
  }

  def killActors(actors: ActorRef*) = {
    actors.foreach { actor =>
      watch(actor)
      system.stop(actor)
      expectTerminated(actor)
    }
  }
}

trait PersistenceCleanup {
  def system: ActorSystem

  val storageLocations = List(
    "akka.persistence.journal.leveldb.dir",
    "akka.persistence.journal.leveldb-shared.store.dir",
    "akka.persistence.snapshot-store.local.dir").map { s =>
    new File(system.settings.config.getString(s))
  }

  def deleteStorageLocations(): Unit = {
    storageLocations.foreach{
      dir => Try(FileUtils.deleteDirectory(dir)) match {
        case Success(e) => system.log.debug(s"Deleting: ${dir.getName} was a success: ${e} ")
        case Failure(e) => system.log.debug(s"Deleting: ${dir.getName} was a failure: ${e} ")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To me what is not working is BeforeEach or AfterEach.

> Is there any know issue ?  isn't it odd that Intellij runs is without
>   issue? Anyone has any idea on that ? Please share experience,
>   solutions or ideas.

Comment: I'm not really sure what's causing the problem, but I have found [in-memory persistence backends](https://github.com/dnvriend/akka-persistence-inmemory) to be useful when testing persistent actors. In-memory backends avoid the whole problem of having to clear persistence directories.